# Add different filter parameters to multiple images

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this command to generate a slideshow with zoompan from a list of images, but it applies the same zoompan to all pictures.

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i img%03d.jpg -i 1.mp3 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.2,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=100" out.mp4
```

How can I get it to have different zoompan parameters for each image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input each image individually and provide a separate [zoompan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan) per image. Then concatenate with the [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter.

```
ffmpeg \
-i img001.jpg \
-i img002.jpg \
-i img003.jpg \
-i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]zoompan[v0]; \
 [1:v]zoompan[v1]; \
 [2:v]zoompan[v2]; \
 [v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 3:a -shortest out.mp4
```

You'll need to adapt this example to use whatever zoompan values you want.

Comment: How could this be done dynamically, without knowing the number of the inputs and applying a filter at random or consequently?

Comment: @TihomirNedev Can't be done using ffmpeg directly. The ffmpeg command will have to be created using scripting.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find a good way to do it. 
Did it with an ugly ffmpeg command string generator. :)